# after starting Kaa log (/var/log/kaa) shows following errors

Tags: kaa

I got some few error as I mentioned below so please I need any expericnced person help

ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed

Answer (score 0):

There could many reasons for that error. And the most obvious one could be of Java. Make sure you are using the latest JDK as instructed at [Single Node Installtion](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-installation/Single-node-installation/). To confirm you use the command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Select the Orcale JDK path for java.
Also if you are using a different SQL Database(default is *kaa*, all small letters) then make sure to update the config file at:

```
sudo nano /etc/kaa-node/conf/sql-dao.properties
```

Finally make sure every service - NoSQL (mongo/cassandra), SQL (mariaDB, PostgreSQL) and Zookeeper is running. Then try running *kaa-node* service.

**Tip:** Kaa node takes some time to integrate with zookeeper. Wait for 3-5 minutes, then refresh the page http://127.0.0.1:8080

Hope it helps!